# Hidden Unallocated Partition greyed out in Flash Drive after Linux Tails Installation

Tags: tails-os

I recently installed Tails (Linux Distro) on my USB drive. I did it using an intermediary USB stick and i discovered when i installed the final Tails OS on the second USB drive that the size of the hard drive reduced from 15.1 GB to 2.43 GB.

I rebooted my system to windows and tried formatting the hard drive, the size remained unchanged.

Please what do i do. The flash drive originally had 15.1GB total disk space andd after the tails installation, it now has 2.43GB.

Comment: This site is to help people using Linux, not those that saw it before and don't have access to it anymore.

Comment: I use linux, i just run it off my USB and i needed the USB for something else so i copied the OS to my windows OS. @JuliePelletier................ Kindly ask before you assume next time. Thanks

Comment: It's the same thing.  You need help on Windows, not Linux.  I was not assuming but merely relying on what you said.

Comment: But the problem was caused by a Linux OS and even when the USB is inserted in a linux system. The partition is still unallocated. But i get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s remove unallocated space. First of all run Windows command line and type `diskpart` in the command prompt. Windows will ask you for Administrator permissions to run the tool. Then run `list disk` command to find your USB flash disk’s number. It should be the same as disk’s number in Computer Management tool. It was 1 in my case. Next you should chose the disk to work with. Type `select disk <disk number>` command, e.g. `select disk 1`. The next step is to clean all volumes and partitions on the disk. Use `clean command` to do that. The last step is to create a primary partition. You can do that using `create partition primary` command. That’s all. You should be able to format your flash disk now.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the partition information with `sfdisk /dev/properDevice -Vl`.

If the remaining 13GBs are not shown, then it is due to a hardware or driver problem.  In that case, testing it on another recent computer would be a good idea and if it still doesn't work, it's a problem with the USB key, probably faked by the one who sold you the key.

You **should** always do a full format on **any** new storage devices unless otherwise noted.

Comment: Hi, i use a windows OS, i dont currently have access to a linux OS. Is there a windows cmd alternative for `sfdisk /dev/properDevice -Vl`

Comment: I used disk management GUI in windows and i discovered that the remain 13GB was there but was unallocated and all other options to either extend the 2.4GB partition or create a new partition with the unallocated partition is greyed out.